# Having syntax errors in my trigger code

Tags: sql

```
USE DATAJASS_PROCESS_DATABASE;
GO
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Tr_ProviderInduction_Insert] 
   ON [dbo].[ProviderInduction]
   AFTER Insert
   AS
      BEGIN
      BEGIN TRY;
      BEGIN TRANSACTION;
      SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
      SET ANSI_PADDING ON;


    UPDATE  ProviderInduction
        set ProviderInduction.CreatedByID = USER_NAME(),
            ProviderInduction.CreatedDateTime = getdate(),
            ProviderInduction.LastUpdateID = USER_NAME(),
            ProviderInduction.LastUpdateDateTime = getdate()            
       FROM (ProviderInduction
            JOIN INSERTED
            on ProviderInduction.Provider_HEUID = INSERTED.Provider_HEUID)
 CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT Provider_HEUID FROM INSERTED
             WHERE INSERTED.EligibilityFlag = 1
             AND INSERTED.SpecialtyCode1 in ('AR', 'ACA', 'PTH', 'ATP', 'AN', 'BBK', 'CTR', 'PCH', 'CIP', 'CLP', 'CCA', 
             'CCE', 'FLX', 'PCP', 'DMP', 'DR', 'EMS', 'FOP', 'HMP', 'HPA', 'HPD', 'HOS','IMA', 'INM', 'MM', 'MGG', 'MGP', 
             'MSR', 'NP', 'RNR', 'NM', 'NR', 'OAN', 'APM', 'PAN', 'PP', 'PDN', 'PDR', 'RO', 'RP', 'R', 'SP', 'SMA', 'VIR','ACC')
            UPDATE ProviderInduction
            SET EligibilityFlag = 2
            FROM ProviderInduction
            JOIN INSERTED
            on ProviderInduction.Provider_HEUID = INSERTED.Provider_HEUID
            WHERE INSERTED.EligibilityFlag = 1
            AND INSERTED.SpecialtyCode1 
            in ('AR', 'ACA', 'PTH', 'ATP', 'AN', 'BBK', 'CTR', 'PCH', 'CIP', 'CLP', 'CCA', 
                'CCE', 'FLX', 'PCP', 'DMP', 'DR', 'EMS', 'FOP', 'HMP', 'HPA', 'HPD', 'HOS','IMA', 'INM', 'MM', 'MGG', 'MGP', 
                'MSR', 'NP', 'RNR', 'NM', 'NR', 'OAN', 'APM', 'PAN', 'PP', 'PDN', 'PDR', 'RO', 'RP', 'R', 'SP', 'SMA', 'VIR','ACC')

 ELSE UPDATE ProviderInduction
       SET EligibilityFlag = 1
       FROM ProviderInduction
       JOIN INSERTED
       on ProviderInduction.Provider_HEUID = INSERTED.Provider_HEUID
       WHERE ProviderInduction.Provider_HEUID= INSERTED.Provider_HEUID


     WHEN INSERTED.AmbCareCode = 3 OR INSERTED.AmbCareCode = 4
        THEN UPDATE ProviderInduction
        SET EligibilityFlag = 2
        FROM ProviderInduction
        JOIN INSERTED
        on ProviderInduction.Provider_HEUID = INSERTED.Provider_HEUID
        WHERE INSERTED.AmbCareCode = 3 OR INSERTED.AmbCareCode = 4

     WHEN INSERTED.AmbCareCode = ''
       THEN UPDATE ProviderInduction
        SET EligibilityFlag =3
        FROM ProviderInduction
        JOIN INSERTED
        on ProviderInduction.Provider_HEUID = INSERTED.Provider_HEUID
        WHERE INSERTED.AmbCareCode = ''

     WHEN INSERTED.AmbCareCode = 2 AND INSERTED.AmbCareFlag = 2
       THEN UPDATE ProviderInduction
        SET EligibilityFlag = 2
        FROM ProviderInduction
        JOIN INSERTED
        on ProviderInduction.Provider_HEUID = INSERTED.Provider_HEUID
        WHERE INSERTED.AmbCareCode = 2 AND INSERTED.AmbCareFlag = 2

     WHEN INSERTED.AmbCareCode = 2 AND INSERTED.AmbCareFlag = ''
       THEN UPDATE ProviderInduction
        SET EligibilityFlag = 3
        FROM ProviderInduction
        JOIN INSERTED
        on ProviderInduction.Provider_HEUID = INSERTED.Provider_HEUID
        WHERE INSERTED.AmbCareCode = 2 AND INSERTED.AmbCareFlag = ''

     WHEN INSERTED.AmbCareCode = 2 AND INSERTED.AmbCareFlag = 1 AND INSERTED.FedFacilityFlag = ''
       THEN UPDATE ProviderInduction
        SET EligibilityFlag = 3
        FROM ProviderInduction
        JOIN INSERTED
        on ProviderInduction.Provider_HEUID = INSERTED.Provider_HEUID
        WHERE INSERTED.AmbCareCode = 2 AND INSERTED.AmbCareFlag = 1 AND INSERTED.FedFacilityFlag = ''

    WHEN INSERTED.AmbCareCode = 2 AND INSERTED.AmbCareFlag = 1 AND INSERTED.FedFacilityFlag = 2 AND INSERTED.PtntsSampleWeekFlag = ''
       THEN UPDATE ProviderInduction
        SET EligibilityFlag = 3
        FROM ProviderInduction
        JOIN INSERTED
        on ProviderInduction.Provider_HEUID = INSERTED.Provider_HEUID
        WHERE INSERTED.AmbCareCode = 2 AND INSERTED.AmbCareFlag = 1 AND INSERTED.FedFacilityFlag = 2 AND INSERTED.PtntsSampleWeekFlag = '' 

    WHEN INSERTED.AmbCareCode= 2 AND INSERTED.AmbCareFlag= 1 AND INSERTED.FedFacilityFlag= 2 AND INSERTED.PtntsSampleWeekFlag= 2
        THEN UPDATE ProviderInduction
        SET EligibilityFlag = 2
        FROM ProviderInduction
        JOIN INSERTED
        on ProviderInduction.Provider_HEUID = INSERTED.Provider_HEUID
        WHERE INSERTED.AmbCareCode= 2 AND INSERTED.AmbCareFlag= 1 AND INSERTED.FedFacilityFlag= 2 AND INSERTED.PtntsSampleWeekFlag= 2

    WHEN INSERTED.AmbCareCode= 2 AND INSERTED.AmbCareFlag= 1 AND INSERTED.FedFacilityFlag= 1 AND INSERTED.PrivatePtntsFlag = ''
        THEN UPDATE ProviderInduction
        SET EligibilityFlag = 3
        FROM ProviderInduction
        JOIN INSERTED
        on ProviderInduction.Provider_HEUID = INSERTED.Provider_HEUID
        WHERE INSERTED.AmbCareCode= 2 AND INSERTED.AmbCareFlag= 1 AND INSERTED.FedFacilityFlag= 1 AND INSERTED.PrivatePtntsFlag = ''

    WHEN INSERTED.AmbCareCode= 2 AND INSERTED.AmbCareFlag= 1 AND INSERTED.FedFacilityFlag= 1 AND INSERTED.PrivatePtntsFlag = 2
        THEN UPDATE ProviderInduction
        SET EligibilityFlag = 2
        FROM ProviderInduction
        JOIN INSERTED
        on ProviderInduction.Provider_HEUID = INSERTED.Provider_HEUID
        WHERE INSERTED.AmbCareCode= 2 AND INSERTED.AmbCareFlag= 1 AND INSERTED.FedFacilityFlag= 1 AND INSERTED.PrivatePtntsFlag = 2

    WHEN INSERTED.AmbCareCode= 2 AND INSERTED.AmbCareFlag= 1 AND INSERTED.FedFacilityFlag= 1 AND INSERTED.PrivatePtntsFlag=2 AND INSERTED.PtntsSampleWeekFlag= ''
        THEN UPDATE ProviderInduction
        SET EligibilityFlag = 3
        FROM ProviderInduction
        JOIN INSERTED
        on ProviderInduction.Provider_HEUID = INSERTED.Provider_HEUID
        WHERE INSERTED.AmbCareCode= 2 AND INSERTED.AmbCareFlag= 1 AND INSERTED.FedFacilityFlag= 1 AND INSERTED.PrivatePtntsFlag=2 AND INSERTED.PtntsSampleWeekFlag= ''

    WHEN INSERTED.AmbCareCode= 2 AND INSERTED.AmbCareFlag= 1 AND INSERTED.FedFacilityFlag= 1 AND INSERTED.PrivatePtntsFlag=2 AND INSERTED.PtntsSampleWeekFlag= 2
        THEN UPDATE ProviderInduction
        SET EligibilityFlag = 2
        FROM ProviderInduction
        JOIN INSERTED
        on ProviderInduction.Provider_HEUID = INSERTED.Provider_HEUID
        WHERE INSERTED.AmbCareCode= 2 AND INSERTED.AmbCareFlag= 1 AND INSERTED.FedFacilityFlag= 1 AND INSERTED.PrivatePtntsFlag=2 AND INSERTED.PtntsSampleWeekFlag= 2

    WHEN INSERTED.AmbCareCode= 1 AND  INSERTED.FedFacilityFlag= ''
        THEN UPDATE ProviderInduction
        SET EligibilityFlag = 3
        FROM ProviderInduction
        JOIN INSERTED
        on ProviderInduction.Provider_HEUID = INSERTED.Provider_HEUID
        WHERE INSERTED.AmbCareCode= 1 AND  INSERTED.FedFacilityFlag= ''

    WHEN INSERTED.AmbCareCode= 1 AND INSERTED.FedFacilityFlag= 1 AND INSERTED.PrivatePtntsFlag= ''
        THEN UPDATE ProviderInduction
        SET EligibilityFlag = 3
        FROM ProviderInduction
        JOIN INSERTED
        on ProviderInduction.Provider_HEUID = INSERTED.Provider_HEUID
        WHERE INSERTED.AmbCareCode= 1 AND INSERTED.FedFacilityFlag= 1 AND INSERTED.PrivatePtntsFlag= ''

    WHEN INSERTED.AmbCareCode= 1 AND INSERTED.FedFacilityFlag= 1 AND INSERTED.PrivatePtntsFlag= 2
        THEN UPDATE ProviderInduction
        SET EligibilityFlag = 2
        FROM ProviderInduction
        JOIN INSERTED
        on ProviderInduction.Provider_HEUID = INSERTED.Provider_HEUID
        WHERE INSERTED.AmbCareCode= 1 AND INSERTED.FedFacilityFlag= 1 AND INSERTED.PrivatePtntsFlag= 2

    WHEN INSERTED.AmbCareCode= 1 AND INSERTED.FedFacilityFlag= 1 AND INSERTED.PrivatePtntsFlag=1 AND INSERTED.PtntsSampleWeekFlag= ''
        THEN UPDATE ProviderInduction
        SET EligibilityFlag = 3
        FROM ProviderInduction
        JOIN INSERTED
        on ProviderInduction.Provider_HEUID = INSERTED.Provider_HEUID
        WHERE INSERTED.AmbCareCode= 1 AND INSERTED.FedFacilityFlag= 1 AND INSERTED.PrivatePtntsFlag=1 AND INSERTED.PtntsSampleWeekFlag= ''

    WHEN INSERTED.AmbCareCode= 1 AND INSERTED.AmbCareFlag= 1 AND INSERTED.FedFacilityFlag= 2 AND INSERTED.PtntsSampleWeekFlag= 2
        THEN UPDATE ProviderInduction
        SET EligibilityFlag = 2
        FROM ProviderInduction
        JOIN INSERTED
        on ProviderInduction.Provider_HEUID = INSERTED.Provider_HEUID
        WHERE INSERTED.AmbCareCode= 1 AND INSERTED.AmbCareFlag= 1 AND INSERTED.FedFacilityFlag= 2 AND INSERTED.PtntsSampleWeekFlag= 2

    WHEN INSERTED.AmbCareCode= 1 AND INSERTED.FedFacilityFlag= 2 AND INSERTED.PtntsSampleWeekFlag= ''
        THEN UPDATE ProviderInduction
        SET EligibilityFlag = 3
        FROM ProviderInduction
        JOIN INSERTED
        on ProviderInduction.Provider_HEUID = INSERTED.Provider_HEUID
        WHERE INSERTED.AmbCareCode= 1 AND INSERTED.FedFacilityFlag= 2 AND INSERTED.PtntsSampleWeekFlag= ''

    WHEN INSERTED.AmbCareCode= 1 AND INSERTED.FedFacilityFlag= 2 AND INSERTED.PtntsSampleWeekFlag= 2
        THEN UPDATE ProviderInduction
        SET EligibilityFlag = 2
        FROM ProviderInduction
        JOIN INSERTED
        on ProviderInduction.Provider_HEUID = INSERTED.Provider_HEUID
        WHERE INSERTED.AmbCareCode= 1 AND INSERTED.FedFacilityFlag= 2 AND INSERTED.PtntsSampleWeekFlag= 2

     ELSE UPDATE ProviderInduction
       SET EligibilityFlag = 1
       FROM ProviderInduction
       JOIN INSERTED
       on ProviderInduction.Provider_HEUID = INSERTED.Provider_HEUID
       WHERE ProviderInduction.Provider_HEUID= INSERTED.Provider_HEUID
END CASE)


COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
THROW;
END CATCH;
END;
```

I'm trying to execute this trigger but I'm getting syntax errors. With the logic, I want the trigger to set eligibilityFlag to 2 when any of the specified codes in SpecialtyCode1 is inserted. And if that condition is true, the trigger should stop right there. And if not, the trigger should go to the next condition and it goes on and on based on the conditions. Any thoughts?

Comment: Well I see a strange `(` right before the table name in the from statement `FROM (ProviderInduction` -- try taking that out.

Comment: I think theres a few rouge `(` and a few `)` missing

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the syntax you're attempting, which can be condensed to this psuedocode:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET SomeColumns=SomeValues
WHERE SomeConditions

CASE WHEN EXISTS(SomeQuery)
UPDATE MyTable ...
```

The CASE expression cannot be used to control whether an UPDATE happens or not.  It can only return a value inside a query.

What you CAN do is use IF statements to control the UPDATEs, but personally, I'd just let every UPDATE run, and filter it with a WHERE clause so that only the desired rows are affected, if they exist at all.   If no rows pass the WHERE clause conditions, the UPDATE won't happen.

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET MyColumn=1
WHERE ConditionsForValue1AreTrue

UPDATE MyTable
SET MyColumn=2
WHERE ConditionsForValue2AreTrue

etc.
```

And finally, as others have noted in comments, you need to closely check the use of parenthesis to eliminate syntax errors caused by those.